# Unable to get Routing Working in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have my Angular 2 application (latest full release not RC or beta) set up with the same structure as on the tutorials (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).  When I put the

```
<base href="/" />
```

on my Index.html I get 404 errors for the following:

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

And this line produces the error "JavaScript runtime error: 'System' is undefined"
    
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });

If I remove the base tag, the above are all fine but I get "No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document."

If I change the base href to

```
<base href="app" />
```

, I don't get any 404 errors above either but I get the error "Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes: "

Below is my app.routing.ts:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BatteriesComponent }  from './batteries/batteries.component';
import { CabinetsComponent }    from './cabinets/cabinets.component';
import { RacksComponent }    from './racks/racks.component';
import { ReportsComponent }    from './reports/reports.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: './app/batteries/batteries',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{ path: 'batteries', component: BatteriesComponent },
{ path: 'cabinets', component: CabinetsComponent },
{ path: 'racks', component: RacksComponent },
{ path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That errors means that your index cannot find the sources you provided.

Is it a possibility that your index.html is different level that the files you are referencing?

```
-src/index, app
-node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js
```

If your setup is like this then you have to do a relative path for your library files being `../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js` etc...

Additionally, your index should have `<base href="/" />` since that is the base and initial for your application bootstrap. All other files will be located relative to that position.

Your routing redirect should link to a path that you have named.
Instead of `'./app/batteries/batteries'` use `'batteries'` for relative redirects or `'/batteries'` for opposite.

If you can post a plnk, that could be most beneficial if these do not suffice.

Comment: Thanks Nico.  I had to put "/MyAppName/" as the href of Base.